# Arraylist remove()

Tags: java, arraylist

I have question ArrayList's remove() method. I want to make if I'm using it correctly. So i have an ArrayList of objects and I'm want to remove a particular object from the Arraylist. Is bool remove(obj) the correct method to use? As I understand it, the remove method compares objects based on the equals method. If the object is a user defined class and the equals method is not overridden, then it should compare objects using == which is comparing addresses rather than content? In this case it would be appropriate to compare addresses rather than content and therefore the remove method is the correct way to remove a particular object from the ArrayList.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You could try and find out ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the correct method to use if you know the object - **you cannot use it when iterating!**. You will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
If you want to remove elements when iterating you need to use the `Iterator`

```
final Iterator<Something> listIter = arrayList.iterator();
while(listIter.hasNext()) {
  final Something thing = listIter.next();
  if(someTest) {
    listIter.remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> As I understand it, the remove method compares objects based on the equals method. If the object is a user defined class and the equals method is not overridden, then it should compare objects using == which is comparing addresses rather than content?

if you don't override your `equals()` it will use default equals from class `Object`

and which compares reference

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return (this == obj);
 }
```

If your class is not direct sub class of Object it will use the overridden `equals()`

For example:

```
Object
|
|--Animal (overrides `equals()`)
    |
    |
  Human (Doesn't override `equals()`, it will use `Animal`'s version of `equals()` not `Object`'s
```

Comment: Which compares reference addresses ...

Comment: @Brian yes that is true